# SPD13 Workflow - Only site admin can start it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, event-receivers

I've put together a mildly complex workflow that is supposed to be able to be started by the average user making a change to a list item. However, my admin account seems to be the only one that can actually trigger it, when anyone else does it the change simply doesn't trigger the workflow.

I have tried: Giving a user full control of the site (ensuring the list and everything in it are inheriting permissions), which produced the same results, and setting up the site to allow workflows to use app permissions and encasing the various steps in the workflow that edit list items into app steps, which also has no effect.

The workflow does write to a couple other lists, but even if the user has full control of those lists and the write steps are in app steps it still does not work. What am I missing?

**Edit:** I've been digging through ULS logs and have compared an item change and subsequent successful workflow to an item change that results in no workflow. The first creates a nice long list of actions that look as you would expect. The second simply enters the monitored scope for the workflow, logs its data, then leaves the scope and no logs appear about the event receiver being fired. I'm convinced it's simply that the event receiver is ignoring these changes made by a non-admin, but I have no idea why or how to fix that.

Comment: Have you looked at the workflow history for the item(s) to verify that the workflows really aren't running?

Comment: Yeah the workflow history shows nothing. I also have my own workflow logging system in place which doesn't even show the workflow starting, and the first thing the workflow is supposed to do is write to that list to indicate it was started.

Comment: Odd.  I've had similar issues in SP2010 when my timer job services got in a bad state.  I'm not familiar enough with the new workflow changes in 2013 to comment on that,  other than to say you might want to check if services are in a good state.

Comment: As far as I can tell the timer service is working perfectly and the Workflow timer job is going off without a hitch. Any more ideas?